# Do certain PDEs guarantee analytic solutions at $t>0$ even if the initial condition at $t=0$ is not analytic?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, functional-inequalities

Are there theorems that guarantee that applying a PDE on a function that is not necessarily analytic at time $t=0$, creates an analytic function at $t>0$?
For example, consider the PDE
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\triangle f}{2},
$$
where $f=f(x,t)$, $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is integrable as a function of $x$ for any fixed $t$ and $\triangle f$ is its Laplacian. The solution at $t=1$ is
$$
f(x,1) = \int f(a,0)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-(x-a)^2/2)da
$$
To see this, $f(x,t)$ can be viewed as the density of the diffusion process $dx_t = dB_t$ with the initial condition that $x_0$ has density $f(x,0)$.
Notice that $f$ is analytic.
If we take the PDE that corresponds to the gradient of the logarithm of $f$, call it $s$, we get the following PDE:
$$
\frac{\partial s}{\partial t} = J_s s + \frac{\triangle s}{2}
$$
where $J_s$ is the Jacobian of $s$ and $\triangle s$ is a vector whose $i$'th entry is the Laplacian of that $i$th entry of $s$.
Notice that if $s$ is the gradient of the logarithm of some integrable function $f$ then the solution of $s$ at $t=1$ is also analytic: indeed, one could obtain its formula by differentiating the logarithm of the the solution for $f$ and see that it is analytic. It seems plausible that $s(x,1)$ is analytic also if $s$ is not the gradient of some function, however, I am not sure how to prove this.

Comment: To show that the solution of the heat equation is analytic you may use the representation with convolution and the Gaussian kernel. In general this is a tough question and you may Google "hypoelliptic"

Comment: @blamethelag so if an operator that corresponds to the evolution of some function is hypoelliptic, does this imply that the operator that corresponds to, say, the gradient of the logarithm of this function, is hypoelliptic as well (under some well behavior assumptions)?

Comment: I do not understand your question sorry. Besides, I am really not an expert on this. I suggest you investigate a book!